# java Xiaolin Wu’s algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, geometry, line

I am trying to programme Xiaolin Wu’s algorithm and I got stuck.

It seems it should works but not, line is completly rasterized witch full opacity, Does anybody has any ide why? thanks a lot. I copared it with pseoudo code and it looks pretty same. I think that the error will be somewhere in selecting colors.

Code:

```
public class LineRasterizerXiaolinWu {

private RasterImage img;
private int color;
double gradient;

public LineRasterizerXiaolinWu(RasterImage img) {
    this.img = img;
}

public RasterImage rasterizeLine(int x1, int y1,
                                 int x2, int y2) {

    RasterImage result = img;

    boolean steep = Math.abs(y2-y1)> Math.abs(x2-x1);

    if(steep){
        int c = y1;
        y1 = x1;
        x1 = c;
        c = x2;
        x2 = y2;
        y2 = c;
    }
    if(x2 < x1) {
        int d = x2;
        x2 = x1;
        x1 = d;
        d = y2;
        y2 = y1;
        y1 = d;
    }

    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;

    if (dx == 0.0){
        gradient =1;
    }else {
        gradient = dy / dx;
    }

    //first end point
    int xEnd = round(x1);
    int yEnd = (int)(y1+gradient*(xEnd-x1));
    int xGap = (int) rfpart(x1+0.5);

    int xPxl1 = xEnd;
    int yPxl1 = (int)ipart(yEnd);

    if (steep) {
        plot(yPxl1, xPxl1, rfpart(yEnd)*xGap);
        plot((yPxl1 + 1), xPxl1, fpart(yEnd)*xGap);
    } else {
        plot(xPxl1, yPxl1, rfpart(yEnd) * xGap);
        plot(xPxl1, yPxl1 + 1, fpart(yEnd) * xGap);
    }

    double intery = yEnd + gradient;

    //second end point
    xEnd = round(x2);
    yEnd = (int)(y2+gradient*(xEnd-x2));
    xGap = (int) rfpart(x2+0.5);

    int xPxl2 = xEnd;
    int yPxl2 = (int)ipart(yEnd);

    if (steep) {
        plot(yPxl2, xPxl2, rfpart(yEnd)*xGap);
        plot((yPxl2 + 1), xPxl2, fpart(yEnd)*xGap);
    } else {
        plot(xPxl2, yPxl2, rfpart(yEnd) * xGap);
        plot(xPxl2, yPxl2 + 1, fpart(yEnd) * xGap);
    }

    if(steep){
        for(int i = xPxl1+1; i<=xPxl2-1; i++){
            plot((int)ipart(intery),i,rfpart(intery));
            plot((int)ipart(intery)+1,i,fpart(intery));
            intery +=gradient;
        }
    }else {
        for(int i = xPxl1+1; i<=xPxl2-1; i++){
            plot(i,(int)ipart(intery),rfpart(intery));
            plot(i,(int)ipart(intery)+1,fpart(intery));
            intery +=gradient;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void plot(int x, int y, double intensity){
    double alfaChanel = Math.round(intensity*100.0)/100.0;

    if (alfaChanel >= 0 && alfaChanel <= 0.2) {
        color =  (new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)).getRGB();
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.2 && alfaChanel <= 0.4) {
        color =  (new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.8f)).getRGB();
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.4 && alfaChanel <= 0.6) {
        color =  (new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.6f)).getRGB();
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.6 && alfaChanel <= 0.8) {
        color =  (new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f)).getRGB();
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.8 && alfaChanel <= 1.0) {
        color =  (new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.2f)).getRGB();
    }



    img.withPixel(x,y,color);
}

//integer part of x
private double ipart (double x){
    return Math.floor(x);
}

private int round (double x){
    return (int) Math.round(x+0.5);
}

//fractional part of x
private double fpart (double x){
    return x-Math.floor(x);
}

private double rfpart (double x){
    return 1-fpart(x);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: not a JAVA coder so I might by wrong but you need to use transparency and I do not see any color mixing with the background in your code. Yes you got some color `if` statements  but that is not how color mixing works. Unless you got Blending enabled on the gfx side you need to read the background pixel and mix it with line color based on alpha value. You are inserting full white instead and only modulate alpha channel with 3 states only which makes no sense to me ....

Comment: You should have something like `color = color0*(1.0-alpha1) + color1*alpha1` where `color0` is original color at pixel position and `color1` is the line color. `alpha1` is the transparency coefficient. Do not forget you need to do this separatelly for each color channel (R,G,B)

Comment: @Spektre I did some updates chcek please edit. This could works, but still nothing :D

Comment: @Spektre it looks much better but I think you are right, I have to mix it with back color.

Comment: Some gfx apis perform blending on their own. If yours is like that then you just need to configure the blending function properly and set the alpha channel of rendered color with your alpha (usually highest 8 bits). Otherwise you need read the target pixel (which in some environments is very slow). You can fake it by using background color constant but that will create artifacts when you are not drawing on empty space

Comment: thank you @Spektre I solved it and posted code. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** with adding this method:

```
 private int blend (int a, int b, float ratio) {
    if (ratio > 1f) {
        ratio = 1f;
    } else if (ratio < 0f) {
        ratio = 0f;
    }

    float iRatio = 1.0f - ratio;

    int aA = (a >> 24 & 0xff);
    int aR = ((a & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int aG = ((a & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int aB = (a & 0xff);

    int bA = (b >> 24 & 0xff);
    int bR = ((b & 0xff0000) >> 16);
    int bG = ((b & 0xff00) >> 8);
    int bB = (b & 0xff);

    int A = (int)((aA * iRatio) + (bA * ratio));
    int R = (int)((aR * iRatio) + (bR * ratio));
    int G = (int)((aG * iRatio) + (bG * ratio));
    int B = (int)((aB * iRatio) + (bB * ratio));

    return A << 24 | R << 16 | G << 8 | B;
}
```

and choosing color like this:

```
private void plot(int x, int y, double intensity){
    double alfaChanel = Math.round(intensity*100.0)/100.0;
    backGroundColor = 0xff2f2f2f;
    drawingColor = 0xffff0000;

    if (alfaChanel >= 0 && alfaChanel <= 0.2) {
        color = blend(backGroundColor,drawingColor,(float)alfaChanel);
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.2 && alfaChanel <= 0.4) {
        color = blend(backGroundColor,drawingColor,(float)alfaChanel);
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.4 && alfaChanel <= 0.6) {
        color = blend(backGroundColor,drawingColor,(float)alfaChanel);
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.6 && alfaChanel <= 0.8) {
        color = blend(backGroundColor,drawingColor,(float)alfaChanel);
    } else if (alfaChanel > 0.8 && alfaChanel <= 1.0) {
        color = blend(backGroundColor,drawingColor,(float)alfaChanel);
    }

    img.withPixel(x,y,color);
}
```

thank you